# Why don't we use POST for all requests and ignore GET?

Tags: web, server, client, web-development-server

I wonder that for all requests from clients to servers. POST can help us to secure data, more safe than GET... So why GET is still exist ?

Comment: don't worry, POST can be unsecure too. it's how you sanitize that's the real security.

Answer (score 0):

These will help you understand why GET still exists:

1. GET requests can be cached
2. GET requests can remain in the browser history
3. GET requests can be bookmarked
4. GET requests can be distributed and shared

Answer (score 0):

> It makes routes more concise, and is a fundimental in create RESTful
> API's. For example I have routes for blog articles, these routes
> implement basic CRUD functionality(Create, Read, Update, Delete) with
> the following routes:
>
> [POST] /api/article | Creates an article [GET] /api/article | Lists
> articles [GET] /api/article/:id | Gets an article by ID [PUT]
> /api/article/:id | Updates and article by ID [DELETE] /api/article/:id
> | Deletes article by ID [DELETE] /api/article | Bulk delete articles
>
> So in this example I only actually have 2 routes "/api/article" and
> "/api/article/:id". But I use 4 different HTTP methods to access them.
> If I were to just use POST, then I'd have 6 different routes, and if I
> wanted to articulate that later on I could end up with a big heaping
> mess of routes, and other developers would not want to work with me.

In addition to the specifications Mustaq Ahmet provided, I believe this example is more tangible to get a sense why GET might be useful. I quoted the answer from [this quora answer](https://qr.ae/pNZvDs)